# Error installing Twit

Tags: json, node.js, twitter-oauth

Wanted to see if I could make a bot (just for myself, not to spam. Obviously!) and took the following steps:

- Download Node.js from the main site.
- Created an app on Twitter and all that stuff.
- Tried it a ton of ways and then read this blog: http://www.apcoder.com/2013/10/03/twitter-bot-20-minutes-node-js/

Now, I am here: https://github.com/ttezel/twit I installed it from the terminal and got back:

```
node_modules/twit
└── oauth@0.9.9
```

Then I went to include the following (with my Twitter app details included) and got pages and pages of errors. I checked on ShellCheck and it's mostly parsing errors. But as it was just copy and paste, I think I must be doing something else wrong.

Any ideas?

```
var Twit = require('twit')

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '...'
  , consumer_secret:      '...'
  , access_token:         '...'
  , access_token_secret:  '...'
})

//
//  tweet 'hello world!'
//
T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'hello world!' }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})

//
//  search twitter for all tweets containing the word 'banana' since Nov. 11, 2011
//
T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'banana since:2011-11-11', count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})

//
//  get the list of user id's that follow @tolga_tezel
//
T.get('followers/ids', { screen_name: 'tolga_tezel' },  function (err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})

//
//  retweet a tweet with id '343360866131001345'
//
T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', { id: '343360866131001345' }, function (err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})

//
//  destroy a tweet with id '343360866131001345'
//
T.post('statuses/destroy/:id', { id: '343360866131001345' }, function (err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})

//
// get `funny` twitter users
//
T.get('users/suggestions/:slug', { slug: 'funny' }, function (err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})

//
// post a tweet with media
//
var b64content = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/img', { encoding: 'base64' })

// first we must post the media to Twitter
T.post('media/upload', { media: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {

  // now we can reference the media and post a tweet (media will attach to the tweet)
  var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string
  var params = { status: 'loving life #nofilter', media_ids: [mediaIdStr] }

  T.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data, response) {
    console.log(data)
  })
})

//
//  stream a sample of public statuses
//
var stream = T.stream('statuses/sample')

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet)
})

//
//  filter the twitter public stream by the word 'mango'.
//
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'mango' })

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet)
})

//
// filter the public stream by the latitude/longitude bounded box of San Francisco
//
var sanFrancisco = [ '-122.75', '36.8', '-121.75', '37.8' ]

var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { locations: sanFrancisco })

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet)
})

//
// filter the public stream by english tweets containing `#apple`
//
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#apple', language: 'en' })

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  console.log(tweet)
})
```